# SQL Query for ID to filter against date

Tags: mysql, sql

basically I have a query that returns back data from a tracking tool. The query is:

```
SELECT `bh`.`bug_id`, `p`.`name` AS `project`, `p2`.`name` AS `portfolio`, `u`.`username` AS `user`,FROM_UNIXTIME( `bh`.`date_modified` ) AS `modify_ts`, 
CASE `b`.`category_id`
when '0' then 'No Category'
when '1' then 'All Projects General'
when '185' then '1. REQ - Requirements'
when '186' then '2. DES - Design'
when '180' then '3. DEV - Development Phase Testing'
when '181' then '4. QAT - Quality Assurance Testing'
when '182' then '5. BAT -Experian Business Accecptance Testing'
when '183' then '6. UAT - External Client User Testing'
when '184' then '7. WAR - Warranty Period'
when '223' then '[Mort Phase 3] 8. Defect Density'
else `b`.`category_id`
END as `Category`,
CASE `b`.`severity`
when '40' then 'Cosmetic'
when '50' then 'Minor'
when '60' then 'Major'
when '70' then 'Critical'
END as `Severity`,
CASE `b`.`priority` 
when '20' then 'Low'
when '30' then 'Medium'
when '40' then 'High'
when '50' then 'Very High'
END as `Priority`,
CASE `b`.`resolution`
when '10' then 'Open' 
when '20' then 'Passed Testing' 
when '60' then 'Duplicate' 
when '70' then 'Change Request' 
when '80' then 'Deferred' 
when '90' then 'Rejected' 
END as `Resolution`,
CASE `b`.`Status` 
when '10' then 'New' 
when '20' then 'Clarification'
when '40' then 'Fixed'
when '50' then 'Open' 
when '80' then 'Ready to test' 
when '90' then 'Closed' 
END as `Status`
FROM `bugtracker`.`mantis_bug_history_table` AS `bh`
LEFT JOIN `bugtracker`.`mantis_bug_table` `b` ON `bh`.`bug_id` = `b`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `bugtracker`.`mantis_user_table` `u` ON `bh`.`user_id` = `u`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `bugtracker`.`mantis_project_table` `p` ON `b`.`project_id` = `p`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `bugtracker`.`mantis_project_hierarchy_table` `ph` ON `b`.`project_id` = `ph`.`child_id`
LEFT JOIN `bugtracker`.`mantis_project_table` `p2` ON `ph`.`parent_id` = `p2`.`id`
```

And an example snippet of the output with columns removed is:

```
> 19213 Triggers UAT    14/08/2014 11:00    Major   Very High   Open    New
19213   Triggers UAT    14/08/2014 11:00    Major   Very High   Open    New
19213   Triggers UAT    14/08/2014 11:00    Major   Very High   Open    New
19213   Triggers UAT    04/08/2014 15:30    Major   Very High   Open    New
19213   Triggers UAT    04/08/2014 15:30    Major   Very High   Open    New
19394   Triggers UAT    15/08/2014 14:24    Major   High    Open    New
19394   Triggers UAT    15/08/2014 14:24    Major   High    Open    New
19394   Triggers UAT    14/08/2014 10:56    Major   High    Open    New
19394   Triggers UAT    14/08/2014 10:56    Major   High    Open    New
19432   Triggers UAT    15/08/2014 14:32    Major   High    Open    New
19432   Triggers UAT    15/08/2014 14:32    Major   High    Open    New
```

What I want to do from within my query is to say for each ID (far left column - `bh`.`bug_id`), then only return the one with the latest date (3rd column - `bh`.`date_modified). Then I can throw a Distinct on top of that for the one's that return back the same if need be.

Is there a way for me to filter that query essentially?

Implemted code added to the query above :

```
FROM `bugtracker`.`mantis_bug_history_table` AS `bh`
INNER JOIN (SELECT `bh`.`bug_id`, MAX(`bh`.`date_modified`)AS `md` FROM `bugtracker`.`mantis_bug_history_table` AS `bh` 
GROUP BY `bh`.`bug_id`) `max_dates` ON `bh`.`bug_id` = `max_dates`.`bug_id` AND `bh`.`date_modified` = `max_dates`.`md`
LEFT JOIN `bugtracker`.`mantis_bug_table` `b` ON `bh`.`bug_id` = `b`.`id`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the max dates like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
...
FROM `bugtracker`.`mantis_bug_history_table` AS `bh`
INNER JOIN (SELECT bug_id, MAX(date_modified) md FROM mantis_bug_history_table GROUP BY bug_id) max_dates ON bh.bug_id = max_dates.bug_id AND bh.date_modified = max_dates.md
LEFT JOIN ...
```

For another example and other ways to solve this, here's this excellent manual entry about [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Comment: where is this max_dates coming from ? table wise?

Comment: It's an alias for the subquery. And md is an alias for max(date_modified).

Comment: Got it working now, thankyou very much @fancyPants .. see code within my question

Answer (score 0):

You can try group by the bug_id and max(date) after you got all the data.

Try `select bug_id,max(date_column),(/*other columns*/) from (/*your sql here*/) as tmp_tabel group by bug_id`

Comment: Thanks for that, I would still have records with the same bug ID present but they would just have different timestamps, how would I only return the latest timestamp for a DISTINCT bug_id ?

Comment: @Alfred w3schools is a horrible website with lots of false information. There's even a website (http://www.w3fools.com/) that warns people of it. Also your answer is wrong, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes the data should filter down from your example above, but with the distinct / group by it returns back 6 rows. @fancyPants what would the correct answer be then if the answer is wrong?

Comment: @kieranbop Well, have a look at my answer ;-)

Comment: @kieranbop It's order by , not group by.

Comment: @Alfred yes that's what I meant :)

Comment: @kieranbop Have you tried order by? What's the result

Comment: @Alfred please see the result added into your answer

Comment: @kieranbop Please never edit answers to add the results of suggested code. Instead put that results into your question. (and notify the answerer about it)

Comment: @kieranbop How about order by both bug_id and date_column and then select distinct

Comment: @Alfred .. This returns the same 6 results unfortunately

Comment: @kieranbop :) sorry for wasting your time. I had tested my statement, and the new answer will be correct.